# How to Monkey patch Rails in a gems and avoid rails regression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, monkeypatching

I wrote some code that **monkeypatch rails** in my project in order to use STI with enum ([More information here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17844))

I currently put this code into an initializer but I feel a little bit afraid by a possible regressions and I will like to **export this in a gem and test it**.

The important things I want is some tests relative to my feature and also to **run some rails tests** at the same time:

- [Inheritance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/inheritance_test.rb)
- [Associations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activerecord/test/cases/associations/eager_load_includes_full_sti_class_test.rb)
- Maybe some others

Do I have to **copy/paste the wanted test into my gem** or can I **call some rails test from my gems** test?

Comment: The link to the issue is broken.

Comment: Since the Rails tests basically use you can add Rails as a dependency of your gem and subclass the tests you want to use. Usually with rails gems such as engines you setup a dummy app which is used to run tests against. Try googling for `testing rails engine`